# Accessing a common method of generically typed objects in a data structure in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to have a datastructure of an abstract class so I can access a method of different objects implementing that abstract class. This is my code:

```
    using Subsync.App;
    List<App> installed_apps = new List<object>();
    public Views (string[] args)
            {
                //INSTALL APPS HERE.
                installed_apps.Add (new HelloWorld.HelloWorld ());
                //INSTALL END

                foreach (App app in installed_apps) {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<object>> match in app.getTokens ()) {
                        tokens.Add (match.Key, match.Value);
                    }
                }

                //begin dispatch
                Dictionary<string,List<object>> tokenized = Tokenize(args);
                Dispatch(tokenized);
            }
```

In namespace Subsync:

```
public abstract class App
    {
        public abstract Dictionary<string, List<object>> getTokens ();
    }
```

In namespace HelloWorld:

```
public class HelloWorld : App
{

    public HelloWorld ()
    {
    }

    public override Dictionary<string, List<object>> getTokens ()
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<object>> ret = new Dictionary<string, List<object>> ();
        ret.Add("helloworld",new List<object>() {"0","-hw","-helloworld"});
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Compiling gives me the error

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace
>   name `App' could not be found. Are you
>   missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference? (CS0246) (App)

All the code files are in the same project folder. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

place abstract as the first class modifier, rather than public.

Comment: Hey... we need our cookies around here on the stack :-D

Comment: +1 In recognition of advanced psychic powers to even have a clue as to what that code is doing !

Comment: you just have to look at the error and you have an idea where to look for the problem.